# MySQL wont import CSV File with µ Symbol

Tags: mysql

Im trying to import a csv file that has the symbol **µ** in of the columns. The destination is just a VARCHAR and the source CSV is UFT-8 Plain text. I get the following error. If i remove the symbol it imports ok but I actually need the symbol stored in the database.

```
Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

ANy ideas appreciated

Comment: [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-character-set) *By default, the server interprets the file contents using the character set indicated by the `character_set_database` system variable. If the file contents use a character set different from this default, it is a good idea to specify that character set by using the **CHARACTER SET clause**.*

Comment: Ok but which character set can handle the symbol  µ ?

Comment: You tell that *the source CSV is UFT-8 Plain text*. So you must use UTF8MB3 or UTF8MB4 (depends on your MySQL version and destination column charset).

Comment: UTF8MB4 is not an import option only UTF8 Latin1, Latin 2 and CP1250. How ca I add UTF8MB4 to the import list in Workbench